# Applying Armature modifier to mesh caused mesh to morph weirdly

Tags: mesh, armature

I downloaded this file with armature and mesh online. In the file, the armature and mesh are in a specific pose already. But the mesh does not have the armature modifier applied to it. Although I can see that the mesh has all the vertex groups and weight painting as per the armature and is well aligned with the armature.

I want to reset the mesh to a T-pose or A-pose, but if I apply the armature to the mesh, the mesh deforms very weirdly. After that if I remove all pose data from pose mode, what I get is the mesh in the same pose as it is now.

How can I get this mesh into the rest mode along with the armature?

[image]

Comment: You need to reset the armature to its rest pose and also align it with the global XYZ, set the origin to the geometry. Then align the limbs of the character to the bones, you can use the Pose brush in Sculpt mode to do that. Now you can parent the character to the armature With Automatic Weights

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am not very good with the Pose brush and sculpt mode in general, is there another way to do this?

Comment: You could do it in Edit mode but it will be much more painful imho

Answer (score 0):

Your armature is not in rest pose, you need to go in *Pose* mode, select all and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>. It is still not correct as it is not aligned with the global axis and also you need to set the origin to the geometry. Another problem is that the character mesh is not aligned with the T pose of the armature. So you have several problems here. A quick way to make the whole thing functional is to select you character, switch to *Sculpt* mode, and use the *Pose* brush to align the character with the armature. It's not ideal but at least you'll be able to move the character with the armature. The long term solution is first to have an armature that is correctly aligned with the global axis but it will be more tedious.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to use the armature to get it all in T pose. I took the current pose and set it as the Rest pose, then I attached the armature to the mesh. Then i copied the original armature and removed the pose from it to get it in a T pose and retargeted the animation from this to the first armature and mesh.